# Expectation of a function of Ito diffusion

Tags: calculus, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, expected-value, stochastic-differential-equations

Given an Ito Diffusion i.e.:

$$
dX(t) = \mu dt + \sigma dW(t)
$$

and a function

$$
k(x) = \lambda x^2
$$

and I want to find the expected value $E[k(X(t)]$ of the function - the only way I know how to do is to average the function evaluated at the solution of the diffusion

$$
E[k(X(t))] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{1}^{n}  k(X_i(t))
$$

where  $n$ is the number of the simulated paths.

If the transition density of the diffusion is known i.e.:

$$
p(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2 \pi \sigma^2 t)} e^\frac{-(x-x_0-\mu t)^2}{2 \sigma^2 t}$$

Can I say that the expectation is also equal to the following?

$$
E[k(X(t))] =  \intop\nolimits_{-\infty}^{\infty} k(x) p(x,t)dx 
$$

where $k(x) = \lambda x^2$ deterministic

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say the expectation is that integral. This is because if $Y$ is a random variable with PDF $f_{Y}$, then the expected value of a function of $Y$, say $g(Y)$, is given by $\mathbb{E}\left[g(Y)\right] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y)f_{Y}(y)\, dy$. See [the law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Comment: I am aware of the law but I was wondering if there were any exceptions for the solution of the sde.

Answer (score -1):

You will need the ito lemma:

For 
$dX_{t}=\mu _{t}\,dt+\sigma _{t}\,dB_{t}$
and
$f=f(t,x)$
,
we have
$ 
df=\left({\frac {\partial f}{\partial t}}+\mu _{t}{\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}}+{\frac {\sigma _{t}^{2}}{2}}{\frac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}}\right)dt+\sigma _{t}{\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}}\,dB_{t}
$

and the required parameter you are looking for is 
$\left({\frac {\partial f}{\partial t}}+\mu _{t}{\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}}+{\frac {\sigma _{t}^{2}}{2}}{\frac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}}\right)$ .